# How to disable/enable a product for admin store programatically in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, multistore, products, programmatically

I want to disable product for **admin store** means product should be disable for **all store/website**. 
I am trying to do something like this but product disable for default store only:

```
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$productObj = $productRepository->get('sku');
$productObj->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
$productRepository->save($productObj);
```

I have also tried to pass global store id i.e. 0 like this but it is also disable only default store.

```
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$productObj = $productRepository->get('sku',true,0,true);
$productObj->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
$productRepository->save($productObj);
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use product action class instead of using product repository and load for each product.

```
private $action;

private $storeManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action $productAction,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->action = $productAction;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}

public function execute() {
    $productIds = [1,2,3];
    $updateAttributes['status'] = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED;

    $storeIds = array_keys($this->storeManager->getStores());
    foreach ($storeIds as $storeId) {
        $this->action->updateAttributes($productIds, $updateAttributes, $storeId);
    }
}
```

Refer what updateAttributes function does [git](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Action.php)

I have not tested this code but hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The above code is giving error.
`Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAttributeId() on boolean in public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Action.php:50`

Comment: Try my updated code I changed this line `$updateAttributes['status'] = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to disable or enable product from magento root

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

$product = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(1);
$product->setStoreId(0) // you can set store id here
$product->setStatus(2); // 2 => Disable , 1 => Enable
$product->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried with above code. It's still enabling/disabling product for default store.

Comment: If you have multiple store and you want to save data by store then you have to set store id before save

Comment: Yes I have multiple store and want to enable/disable to admin store only. I have also mention in my question.
Where I can set store id in above code?